# Bluetooth device connected but not showing up in Output Device

Tags: mac, audio, bluetooth

In order to remove another audio device from my Mac, I deleted the HAL folder from Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/ (This is the advice I got from a quick google search, I don't understand the mechanics of it at all)

It removed the device I wanted to remove but now my Galaxy buds are not working. They connect to the bluetooth successfully for a few seconds and then disconnect automatically. Even when they are connected, the headphones do not show up in the list of Output devices.

If someone has any solutions, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would remove unwanted drivers from *within* the HAL folder, not the HAL folder its self. I don't think deleting HAL/ is a good idea as that's where audio drivers go. Probably you should

1. Recreate it in the terminal with `sudo mkdir -p /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL && sudo chown root:wheel /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL && sudo chmod 0775 /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL`
2. Reinstall any software/drivers for your hardware

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. Can you please guide me through how I can do these?

1. I opened the terminal, and pasted this command. Then it asked me for the password to my MacBook which i entered. Anything else I have to do?

2. How can I reinstall the software/drivers?

Thank you.

Comment: This would be specific to your hardware. I suggest to contact the manufacturer support if you cannot figure out their driver re-installation.